# Permissions ignored when writing a file

Tags: windows, go, permissions, file-permissions, read-write

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {
    ioutil.WriteFile("test.txt", []byte("Hello world"), 0222)

    b, e := ioutil.ReadFile("test.txt")
    check(e)

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

I'm using the `io/ioutil` package to read/write a file, and setting the permissions to 0222 (write, write, write) when writing the file still allows me to read the file after it's written.

Using `stat test.txt` in Bash, the access shows as `(0644/-rw-r--r--)`.

Why is the file written with 0644 permissions and not the specified 0222?

Comment: Does the file `test.txt` exist before you run this program? The [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile) say "If the file does not exist, WriteFile creates it with permissions perm; otherwise WriteFile truncates it before writing.". This means, if the file is already present, `WriteFile()` won't modify the perms.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't exist. Completely clean directory, only containing main.go. The newly created file always has access permissions of 0644.

Comment: What is your executing user's umask?

Comment: `test.txt` already exists with permission `0644`. I would expect this file to be written out with only `0200` if you have a default umask.

Comment: @JimB `test.txt` doesn't exist at all before this code is run. I don't know what 'default unmask' is, but I would assume I'm using the default as I haven't made any attempts to change it (wouldn't know how). I'm on Windows if that helps?

Comment: oh, you're on windows, that probably has something to do with it. It may be that since `0222` doesn't really make sense, it adds appropriate read permissions as well.

Comment: Windows doesn't have numerical permissions, it has a different model. Bash is just faking it to the Linux model as Linux tools expect it to be there

Comment: The permissions get ignored. Ultimately it calls `syscall.Open`. Confirm this for yourself in the Windows implementation of [`syscall.Open`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.11/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go#L247). Also, like a lot of POSIX-over-Windows tools, their [syscall.Chmod](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.11/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go#L538) sets the file's readonly attribute if write access isn't allowed.